# How to get last value of an array input text in JS?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code from controller where I used looping to show this.

```
<input type="hidden" class="notif_date" value="'.$created_at.'">
```

the sample data of this are multiple dates: `2019-05-28 13:45:45`

Now I'm trying the get the last date that will be shown using JavaScript.

Currently I have this code:

```
var last_date =  document.getElementsByClassName("notif_date");
console.log(last_date);
```

But this only gets the array of input types

[image]

So I tried to use `last()` and place like this `console.log(last_date.last());` and this gives me an error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: last_date.last is not a function

How can I get the last value of date using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get last element you can use following code

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("notif_date");
console.log(elements[elements.length-1]);
```

This code will provide you the correct output which you want.

**Edited**

If you want to get value of last element then use this:-

```
console.log(elements[elements.length-1].val());
```

**Note:** But you can't get value directly from `document.getElementsByClassName("notif_date")`. Because this return multiple object of multiple class elements.

But if you want to get value of all the elements then you need to loop this.

Comment: @KingRG no you can not use .val() directly here, that is a jQuery thing. You could wrap `elements[elements.length-1]` in `$()` first to create a jQuery object - but you can also just access the value directly using `.value`, that doesn’t need jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Using new [Array.prototype.at()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method.

```
let elements = [...document.getElementsByClassName("notif_date")];
let last_input = elements.at(-1);
let last_value = elements.at(-1).value;

console.log(last_input, last_value);
```